# Parsing IMS response in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, encoding, ibm-mq

I am trying to communicate with IMS from a Java EE[JMS based] based application through WebSphere MQ. While i do get an output, the output ByteMessage that i receive is encode.

I use the following to talk to IMS

JMS program with resource configured in WAS 7 would talk to WebSphere MQ that would in turn forward the message to IMS

While i do get a response from IMS, the CCSID and encoding values are changed as below

```
JMS_IBM_Character_Set: 500
JMS_IBM_Encoding: 785
JMS_IBM_Format: MQIMS   
JMS_IBM_MsgType: 2
JMS_IBM_PutApplType: 20
```

1) Is there any specific setting in WebSphere that determines the format of the message
I have CCSID [819] and encoding [273] set. I have also checked the option to "Append RFH version 2 headers.."

2) Is there a way to parse the response message ?

Comment: Just to update - I had to read/parse the response as JMS message instead of an IMS message - i didnt realize this until the MQ admin informed me that the message is a JMS message.